# React router render method with HOC

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm trying to implemenent this logic inside react-router-dom (5.0.1). This is my route:

```
    <Route
      path="/available-days"
      render={props => isAdmin ? Auth(UserProfileView) : <Redirect to='/dashboard'/>}
      />
```

When `idAdmin`is `true` it causes the error: `Objects are not valid as a React child`.
I also tried this:

```
    <Route
      path="/available-days"
      render={props => isAdmin ? Auth(UserProfileView)({ ...props }) : <Redirect to='/dashboard'/>}
    />
```

Then I see `TypeError: Object(...)(...) is not a function`. Why I just cannot use HOC inside the render method and how can I make it work? Btw `Auth(UserProfileView)` works fine if put in component method.

Comment: Why don't you just use `<UserProfileView {...props} />` and then wrap `UserProfileView` with `Auth` in that component only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don’t Use HOCs Inside the render Method, see here https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html .

You can try

const UserProfileViewWithAuth = Auth(UserProfileView)

```
<Route
   path="/available-days"
   render={props => isAdmin ? <UserProfileViewWithAuth {...props} /> : <Redirect to='/dashboard'/>}
/>
```